# impdp with PARALLEL not working

Tags: database, oracle, impdp

I would like to load Oracle dump files in parallel. I have 23 cores on my machine. All the dump files were created using expdp.

To do so, I ran this command:

```
impdp $RMS_SCHEMA/amadeus@$TWO_TASK directory=RMS_DUMP_DIR2 dumpfile=Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.%U.dmp logfile=import.log PARALLEL=33
```

Unfortunately, the import is not any faster.

Here's what I get when I show the status of my datapump_job

```
Import> status

Job: SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01
  Operation: IMPORT
  Mode: TABLE
  State: EXECUTING
  Bytes Processed: 1,324,932,752
  Percent Done: 6
  Current Parallelism: 5
  Job Error Count: 0
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.%u.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.01.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.02.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.03.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.04.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.05.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.06.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.07.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.08.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.09.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.10.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.11.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.12.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.13.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.14.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.15.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.16.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.17.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.18.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.19.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.20.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.21.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.22.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.23.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.24.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.25.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.26.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.27.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.28.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.29.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.30.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.31.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.32.dmp
  Dump File: /data2/rms/dump/Auto_SK_LAD_MIG04.33.dmp

Worker 1 Status:
  Process Name: DW00
  State: EXECUTING
  Object Schema: OWNRMSABE_AIR_SK
  Object Name: LAD_AVAILABILITY_MIG04
  Object Type: TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
  Completed Objects: 6
  Completed Rows: 576,351
  Completed Bytes: 295,161,304
  Percent Done: 53
  Worker Parallelism: 1
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. For those interested: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2294237

Comment: I expect you could get around it by running separate impede processes, one per named partition.

Comment: I find it much more elegant to let Oracle do the parallelism by itself. Plus,  this is exactly what I wanted!